# Codeigniter Route multiple domains to same controller and function but with different parameters

Tags: dns, routes

Is there a way to route multiple domains to a single controller/function but with different parameters?

For example:

```
some_domain.com  -> sites/display/site_slug_1
other_domain.com -> sites/display/site_slug_2
```

"sites" is the controller and "display" is the function.

Is it possible to just add new domains to the routes.php file and have them redirected to the proper uri's?

---

Can't answer my own question so I'm posting the solution here:

I ended up adding something like this to the routes.php file

```
//define each domain and it's route
$sites_routes = array();
$sites_routes['domain1.com'] = 'sites/display/site_slug_1';
$sites_routes['domain2.com'] = 'sites/display/site_slug_2';

//get domain name
$host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
preg_match("/[^\.\/]+\.[^\.\/]+$/", $host, $matches);
//define each domain and it's route
$sites_routes = array();
$sites_routes['domain1.com'] = 'sites/display/site_slug_1';
$sites_routes['domain2.com'] = 'sites/display/site_slug_2';

//get domain name
$host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
preg_match("/[^\.\/]+\.[^\.\/]+$/", $host, $matches);

//build the routes
if(isset($sites_routes[$matches[0]]))
{    
    $route['default_controller']       = $sites_routes[$matches[0]];    
    $route['(:any)']                   = $sites_routes[$matches[0]].'/$1';       
}
else
{
    $route['default_controller']       = 'home';    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use .htaccess on the different domains to do the mapping

Comment: I thought about using .htaccess but in this particular case it was out of the question, I'm not allowed to do any changes there.

Answer (score -1):

```
//get domain name
    $host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
    preg_match("/[^\.\/]+\.[^\.\/]+$/", $host, $matches);
    //define each domain and it's route
    $sites_routes = array();
    $sites_routes['meilibosi.com'] = 'mlbs';
    $sites_routes['qunar.ir'] = 'longyueco';

    //get domain name
    $host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
    preg_match("/[^\.\/]+\.[^\.\/]+$/", $host, $matches);

    //build the routes
    if(isset($sites_routes[$matches[0]]))
    {
        $route['default_controller']       = $sites_routes[$matches[0]];
        $route['(:any)']                   = $sites_routes[$matches[0]]."/$1";
    }
    else
    {
        $route['default_controller']       = "mlbs";
    }
```

Comment: I have the same issue my site its a multiple language and with this code I have error on changing site 1 language, and for site 2 I got nothing...

Comment: Please don't write code only - add a description to help all of us understand you reasoning to solve the problem 